# Is it possible (and how) to check whether given type is serializable by protobuf-net?

Tags: protobuf-net

What I mean here is not how to check whether user defined classes have ProtoContract attribute, but rather how to check whether type is one of those types which has serialization  way predefined. For example `DateTime` and `List<int>` are serializable but an `object` obviously not. Does protobuf-net provide some predicate to test that?

Comment: There is a method on TypeModel to handle message/contract types - but it doesn't specify primitives; any use?

Comment: Do you mean CanSerializeContractType? If it fails with int given, but returns true with the user created type that contains int, then yes, it will be useful :) My basic need is to decide whether class can be successfully serialized (concerning its types). Let me try it.

Comment: I could add something that reports whether basic types can be handled - that help?

Comment: It would be nice, definitely. I could build my own list of basic types, but then I would have to keep it up to date with the protobuf-net's one which is not good solution.